# Adding two input values in one state Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a field of `trip_start` and `trip_end` in one state called `name` so that when  I send the data, it's combined into one field `name`.

This is what happens when I submit the data, when I click the first time the state for `name` shows null, when I click for the second time that's when the state of `name` is populated with the data of `trip_start` and `trip_end`.

Below is my code :

```js
export class DriverPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            trip_start:'',
            trip_end:'',
            nameError:'',
            details:'',
            detailsError:'',
            price: '',
            priceError:'',
            driver_name: localStorage.getItem('username')
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('state ', this.state.name)
        this.setState({name:''+this.state.trip_start+' to ' + this.state.trip_end});

       };

  handleChange =(evt) => {
        this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
    }
```

Below is my component which contains the HTML code :

```js
export const DriverComponent = ({handleSubmit, handleChange,obj})=>(

    <div className={'bg-image'}>
            <Card className={'landing-card'}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Row>
                    <Col s={12} m={12} l={12}>
                        <label s={12} l={12} className={'header'}>  Make Ride Request </label>
                    </Col>
                    <Input s={12} l={12} type={'text'} value={obj.trip_start} label="Trip Start" name='trip_start'  onChange={handleChange}/>

                    <Input s={12} l={12} type={'text'} value={obj.trip_end} label="Trip End" name='trip_end'  onChange={handleChange}/>

                    <Col s={12} m={12} l={6}>
                        <div className={'errors'} s={10}>{obj.nameError}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <div className="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea id="details" name='details' onChange={handleChange} className="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                        <label htmlFor="details">Trip Details</label>
                    </div>
                    <Col s={12} m={12} l={6}>
                        <div className={'errors'}>{obj.detailsError}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Input s={12} l={12} type="text" value={obj.price} label="Price" name='price' onChange={handleChange} />
                    <Col s={12} m={12} l={6}>
                        <div className={'errors'}>{obj.priceError}</div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col s={12} m={12} l={12}>
                        <Button waves='light' className={`purple button-align`} value='submit' type='submit' >Create Ride Request</Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                </form>
            </Card>
    </div>
);
```

So in summary, I want the state `trip_start` and `trip_end` to be concatenated on the state `name` instantly while am going to send the data.

For example this is a simple pseudo code for what I want to achieve:

```js
trip_start = new york
trip_end = toronto

name = trip_start + "to " +trip_end

Output 

name = new york to toronto
```

Comment: What do you mean under "the data set itself after clicking it twice". Do you mean a form submit? Where do you want to combine this fields?

Comment: I think better you keep two values separate, it will help you to manage form easier

Comment: @Kort, I have edited that line.

Comment: @HafeezHamza, please give me a clue.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have two state values to track; if you want `name` to track those changes, when you update either input, you should update the `name` state.

Comment: is double-clicking the submit button is your only problem, then change `handleSubmit` `setState` to the following `this.setState({name:''+this.state.trip_start+' to ' + this.state.trip_end}, () => console.log(this.state.name));`

Comment: @DaveNewton, I have included a pseudo code at the bottom of the post, I think this could make more expalnation.

Comment: @IdrisStack please add a code for `handleChange()`

Comment: @Kort, I have shared it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why it has to be concatenated **before** submission? Seems like you're making your life harder by combining two **asynchronous** strings **synchronously**. Instead, just make your life easier and concatenate **upon** form submission.

Concatenated on form submission example (best solution): https://codesandbox.io/s/10w18m5z54

**containers/Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Fields from "../components/Fields";

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    tripStart: "",
    tripEnd: ""
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) =>
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { tripEnd, tripStart } = this.state;
    const name = `${tripStart} to ${tripEnd}`;
    alert(name);
  };

  render = () => (
    <Fields
      {...this.state}
      handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      onHandleChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Concatenated on input change example (works, but **not** an ideal solution as it causes double rerendering -- also, `this.state.name` is never used in your component, so utilizing `state` is **unnecessary** and **not recommended**!): https://codesandbox.io/s/nk66v4rk9j

**containers/Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Fields from "../components/Fields";

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    tripStart: "",
    tripEnd: ""
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) =>
    this.setState(
      {
        [name]: value
      },
      () =>
        this.setState({
          name: `${this.state.tripStart} to ${this.state.tripEnd}`
        })
    );

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name } = this.state;
    alert(name);
  };

  render = () => (
    <Fields
      {...this.state}
      handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      onHandleChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```